# Displaying images with selected options

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a site for questions and answers in which few multiple choice questions will be displayed and the user would have to select radio buttons to answer the questions. After submitting, right and wrong answers would displayed and user would be given the option of seeing the correct answer.
In this page for seeing correct answers what I want to do is to show an image of tick mark for the correct option and a cross image for all other wrong options. But I am facing problems in writing the logic.
This is what I have done till now.

**This page is for selecting which image is to be displayed**

```
<?

        session_start() ; 
        $wrong =  array() ;
        if( !empty($_SESSION['wrongAnswer'] ) )  {
            $wrong = $_SESSION['wrongAnswer'] ;//wrongAnswer array has  
                                               //ids of wrongly answered 
                                               //questions         

            session_destroy() ;
        }

        if( !empty($_POST['wrongAnswer'] ) )  {
            $wrong = $_POST['wrongAnswer'] ; 
        }

        $i = 0 ;
        $quesID = ""; 
        $question = "" ;
        require_once "connection.php";  
        foreach ($wrong as $n) {     

       <?  $query = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = '$n' " ;
            if($result = $mysqli->query( $query ) )  {
               if( $row = $result->fetch_object() ){
                    $answer = $row->answer ;

                 // $count++;
                }
                else 
                    echo "Couldn't tally answer " . $mysqli->error ;

            }

            else
                echo "Error executing query" . $mysqli->error ;


                                  //<----- THIS IS WHERE THE WRONGLY ANSWERED QUESTIONS WILL BE DISPLAYED WITH IMAGES AS MENTIONED BEFORE ------>//

                $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questionid='$n' " ;
                 $i ++ ;
                 if( $result = $mysqli->query( $query ) )  {  
                     $count= $result->num_rows ;
                      echo '<form name = "checkans.php" action = "checkans.php" method = "POST" >' ;

                     $row = $result->fetch_object()  ; 
                              //  $i++ ;
                               $quesID = $row->questionid ;
                               $question = $row->question ;

                                $quesID = $row->questionid ;
                                $query2 = "SELECT option1,option2,option3,option4 FROM options WHERE questionid='$quesID'" ;
                                if($result2 = $mysqli->query($query2) )  {
                                    if($row2 = $result2->fetch_object() )  {
                                        $option1 = $row2->option1 ;
                                        $option2 = $row2->option2 ;
                                        $option3 = $row2->option3 ;
                                        $option4 = $row2->option4 ;

                                       ?>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <?  echo "<div  id = $row->questionid name = boxs>" ; ?>
                <th> <h2> <? echo $i .")" ; ?>  </h2>  </th> 
                <th> <h2> <?echo $row->question ;?> </h2> </th> 

          <tr>  <input type="hidden" name="quesID[]" id="<? echo $quesID ; ?>" value="<? echo $quesID ; ?>">
            <div id = "options">
            <td>
            <span id = "1"> 
            <img id = "image" height="50px" width="50px">
            </td>
          <td>  
        <label>
          <? echo $option1 ;?>
        </label>
            </td>
        </span>

        <td>
        <span id = "2">
            <img id = "image" height="50px" width="50px">

          </td>
          <td>
        <label>
          <? echo $option2 ;?>
        </label>
        </td>
        </span>

        <td>
        <span id = "3">
            <img id = "image" height="50px" width="50px">

          </td>
          <td>
        <label>
          <? echo $option3 ;?>
        </label>
        </td>
          </span>

          <td>
          <span id = "4">
            <img id = "image" height="50px" width="50px">



          </td>

          <td>
        <label>
          <? echo $option4 ;?>
        </label>
        </td>
            </div>

        </span>
        </div>

              </tr>

          </table> 
            </section>
        <?          
                                    }
                                    else 
                                        echo "No options available for this question" ;
                                }


         }
         ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
                var i = 0
                for(i=1; i <= 4; i++)  {
                    var y = document.getElementById(i);
                    //alert(y.childNodes)
                    var x = document.getElementById("image");
                    if( y.id ==  (<?echo $answer ; ?>) )  {
                        x.src = "correct.png" ;
                    }
                    else
                        x.src = "wrong.jpg" ;


                }


        }

    </script>
    <?
       }
    ?>
```

Thing wrong with my code is that it just displays image for only 1 question and that too with the wrong option.